# Javascript & CGI How to open div and pass arguments in same time

Tags: javascript

I have to change my code a little bit to add jquery popup window.

So far I just open new window using:

```
<a href="?action=_edit&amp;_code=code"><img src...
```

In new version I simply open popup window using:

```
<a href="#myDialog" data-toggle="modal" onclick="">...
```

It works in terms of open dialog box, the only problem remains is how to pass arguments from ?action=_edit&_code=code in this case ?

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use more data tags, for example, `data-action`, and `data-code`. These can then be obtained in your on click handler.

This link here might give you a better idea: http://www.slideshare.net/lensco/html5-data-attributes